# Filter the Feature Layer parameter in Python Script Tool

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, filter, python-script-tool

I have a Python script tool where I have a parameter of type Feature Layer because I want to have the already opened layers as a dropdown list.

I was wondering if there is a way to filter this Feature Layer parameter dropdown list in order to show Polygon **Shapefiles** only?

Comment: Did you search for similar problems on the forum? This seems like an answer to your question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67473/how-to-limit-input-of-python-script-parameter-to-polyline-only-when-using-layer

Comment: The possible duplicate show how to handle the type of features shown on the dropdown list. I want to filter the list just for the shapefiles to be visible as well.

Comment: Can you include a code snippet that illustrates how you are receiving this parameter (and perhaps printing its value), and then a picture of its tool properties showing how you have this parameter being configured, please?  If you are already using any tool validation code then including that as text would be useful too.

Comment: I have the answer with the code ready to post. Mind opening the question?

Comment: @PolyGeo, this question does not require a code snippet to understand and answer, for someone familiar with the task at hand. This is evidenced by the fact that someone already has an answer to give. Please open the question back up.

Comment: @Alex Tereshenkov--you need to put @ before the person's handle for them to get your message.

Comment: Do you want this for a python toolbox or a custom toolbox? It makes a difference in the answer. You can apply a filter to the input parameters  (which is something you can look up in your ESRI help files, if you get tired of waiting for an answer).

Comment: @PolyGeo, could you please open the question?

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov I've just re-opened this. If anyone had edited the question then the review queue may have seen this re-open hours ago. I voted to place it on hold but there are 190 people who can vote to re-open if it hits the queue.

Comment: @RHB it does not necessarily need what I asked for but if the question had been improved to include it then the field of potential answerers would have been broadened. Had it been included originally then I would not have voted to close it.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [ToolValidator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Programming_a_ToolValidator_class/00150000000v000000/) class for that.

1. Create a parameter of type `String` in script tool. Set the `Filter` to be the `Value List`. Leave the list empty.
2. Edit the script tool Python file.

```or-tag-here
import arcpy
in_layer_name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
in_layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_layer_name,"out_fl")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_layer,"OUT_TEST")
```

3. Edit the ToolValidator class' `initializeParameters`.

```or-tag-here
def initializeParameters(self):
    """Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is
    called when the tool is opened."""
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
    lyrs = [lyr for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "",df)
            if lyr.dataSource[-4:] == ".shp" and
            arcpy.Describe(lyr.dataSource).shapeType == "Polygon"]

    self.params[0].filter.list = [lyr.longName for lyr in lyrs]
    return
```

Now you will get the list of layer names (as strings) in the drop-down list of the parameter. You just need to make those feature layers (which is done on the 3rd line in the script tool file above).

Comment: Thanks. I will implement it and let you know if it works as I am expecting. :-)

Comment: I implemented it like this:
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    lyrs = [lyr for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd) if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE") and lyr.dataSource[-4:] == ".shp" and arcpy.Describe(lyr.dataSource).shapeType == "Polygon"]
    self.params[1].filter.list = [lyr.longName for lyr in lyrs]
but the result is not what I want.
The String hides the icon on the right of the parameter, so the user can choose sth outside the mxd.
Is there a way to get the Feature Layer list in ToolValidator, filter it and put it back?

Comment: Please ask a new question about that