# Feature Layer parameter showing only Polygon Shapefiles

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, python-script-tool, string, tool-validation

I have created a Python Tool in ArcGIS where most of the paramaters musts be ONLY **Polygon Shapefiles**. You can also look on my previous question:
[Filter the Feature Layer parameter in Python Script Tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183409/filter-the-feature-layer-parameter-in-python-script-tool/183517?noredirect=1#comment280057_183517)
Also, the user must be able to select ONLY **Polygon Shapefiles** either from the current MXD or his/her system.

In order to solve it, I tried to give the type "Feature Layer" on each parameter and filter them to show only polygons. But, I didn't manage to put the extra filter for **Shapefiles**. In this case it is the only think I miss.

[image: FeatureLayerfilteredPolygons]

The second attempt was the implementation of the answer on my previous question:

[Filter the Feature Layer parameter in Python Script Tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183409/filter-the-feature-layer-parameter-in-python-script-tool/183517?noredirect=1#comment280057_183517)

In this case, I had to enrich the suggested code with:

```
    lyr.supports("DATASOURCE")
```

because I have groups in my data frames. I got the list of Polygon Shapefiles that are already open in the current MXD but I don't have the option to select a shapefile from the user system because (as suggested) the parameter type is **String** (the folder icon on the right side of the field is missing!).

[image: FilteredStringField]

To conclude:

- Is there a way to filter the dropdown list of Feature Layer parameter inside ToolValidator, so that it shows ONLY Shapefiles (Polygons are already filtered)?
- If the above is NO, then is there a way to add the folder icon next to the String parameter so that the user can select an external Polygon Shapefile?
- If none of the above two answers are YES, then is there any other solution?